# Is There a -Weffc++ Equivalent for MSVC (Visual C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I would like to know, is there a MSVC(++) equivalent for the `-Weffc++` flag? What number is it?

I didn't see anything like it in the list of compiler warnings/errors on the [MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4800-through-c4999?view=vs-2017).

Comment: What compiler uses the `-Weffc++` flag?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not any equivalent.

Visual C++ doesn't have warning groups at all, only the warning level slider, and the ability to disable individual warnings.  So none of the GCC/clang warning group options have an equivalent.

Beyond that, the Effective C++ book is rather old and some of its advice is no longer considered to be best practices.  So enforcement has minimal value.

Some editions of Visual C++ come with code analysis, which has many more of these checks than the basic compiler.  That's turned on using `/analyze`, documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-overview

Comment: Do you know if there are any tools or additional flags that hint at a member of a class not being initialized?

Comment: @9301293: That seems to be [C++ Core Guideline C.41](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-complete) ... unfortunately it doesn't look like Visual C++ has an analysis rule for that one yet.  But [there are other tools for checking the Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-tools).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly equivalent probably not, but starting from Visual Studio 2015 there is [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) checkers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers